# Adding timestamp to index.html file

Tags: javascript, webpack, unix-timestamp

Is there any way of appending a unix timestamp in the index.html source path using webpack?
i've found plugin such as webpack-timestamp-plugin but i don't think it will do the trick.[https://www.npmjs.com/package/timestamp-webpack-plugin#output][1]

Comment: so, how do you want your HTML file to change? do you want the name to change? something in the file to change? why don't you think the plugin will work?

Comment: I think i wrote the que a bit wrong, i want the unix timestamp as filename .For eg; 'index-theunixtimestamphere.html'. The plugin doesn't provide the unix formatted timestamp so won't work for me.sry if i couldn't explain the question properly

Comment: ah, okay. I'd use a bash script...